# Calling a asmx Web Service from a WCF Service

Tags: .net, silverlight, wcf, asmx

I have an interesting problem with an application (silverlight) that needs to obtain some data from a wcf service. No brainer all good on that front and easy to do.

The wcf service needs to call another asmx web service to get more bit data to complete the retrieval. Clearly this causes problems in normal async event, as once the wcf method is run it needs to create another async call to the asmx service to retrieve the data.

If this is possible could someone point me in the right direction of how to handle this please.

Thanks for your time

Comment: May I ask why this isn't provided in the initial WCF call (the details you need to further query)?

Comment: Can you not call the asmx service synchronously?

Comment: I didn't understood what is you actually want to do? the problem is take time? if the issue is time out? increase the times in bindings timeouts attributes. if the problem is time? go with vc 74 comment

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm fairly new to this stuff. Yes just called it all synchronously. First project I've heavily used Web services and as such always been doing calls async way, didn't occur to me at first just a sync call is fine due to the client is the one that needs to wait anyway so no need for it. All good and all running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case that you, for some far-fetched reason, cannot call the ASMX service synchronously (which is by far the better solution) you can try something like this (pseudo code though):

```
public MyResultClass GetStuff(ParamClass myParameter)
{
    var proxy = new ASMXProxy();
    proxy.Url = Settings.Default.ASMXUrl;
    var synchhandle = proxy.BeginGetStuff(myParamater);
    while(synchhandle.IsCompleted == false)
    {
        //Do stuff here
    }
    return proxy.EndGetStuff(synchhandle); //Code will block here until done
}
```

You can leave out the while loop if you don't need to do other stuff while the call is being made.

Comment: Thanks Vincent, I just used called it synchronously in the end.